v-radio button problem to change after take value on the database in vuejs and vuetify
i have a big problem on the vuejs and vuetify.
The problem is on the radio button.
I want to show the value of the radio button in the interfaces and i can change the value after , but it's not working.
The value on the database is on : item.etat ,
And the value of v-model is on :
item.selectedValue
Here is my code :
//This is the table component.
<v-data-table headers=headers items=items>
<template v-slot:item.radio="{ item }">
      <p>Selected Button: {{ item.selectedValue = item.etat }}</p> 
      <v-radio-group v-model="item.selectedValue" class="mr-3" inline>
        <v-radio label="Non Atteint" :value=1></v-radio>
        <v-radio label="P. Atteint" :value=2></v-radio>
        <v-radio label="Atteint" :value=3></v-radio>
      </v-radio-group>
    </template>
</v-data-table>

//This is the header of table on the view component :  
Heard1 = [ 
text: ''  value key:radio]




Is the template you're in a table or something? I think you can not change item properties directly, you should handle the update event and change the value upper. Please provide a more complete example.

What are you doing here: {{item.selectedValue = item.etat }}? If the slot comes from VDataTable, I think item is the internal table item, not the data object you put into the table. Check the other item props, ther should be something like raw.

@MarioSantini , yes the template is in the v-data-table , please wait , i send some code

@MoritzRingler i affect the value of item.selected to item.etat , for the value on the database  , my problem of this , i can't change the value of the radio button

So, I think your issue is that you assign item.selectedValue to item.etat and that will overwrite any changes from the selection of radio buttons.

@MarioSantini , yes  this is the problem , but i want some issue to assign value of item.selectedValue who item.selectedValue = item.etat.
i want item.selectedValue take 2 ways binding.
One : take value of radio button
Two : Take the value of item.etat

If your aim is to change item.etat, you don't need item.selectedValue at all, just put the item.etat on the v-model and let the widget change the value. If you need to do some checks before saving item.etat, then you should initialize item.selectedValue before using it in the template, maybe with a computed function that wrap your data.
